# Filtering in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app using Firebase in which data structure consists of Hotel table consisting of city name along with latitude and longitude as shown in below image. 
[image]

Now when user opens the app, her location is fetched having details like latitude, longitude, city name etc of user.Using these information i want to display list of hotels that are near to user using Firebase. How can i achieve this. Please help and Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) to be what you're looking for:

> GeoFire is set of open-source libraries for JavaScript, Objective-C,
>   and Java that allow you to store and query a set of keys based on
>   their geographic location. At its heart, GeoFire simply stores
>   locations with string keys. Its main benefit, however, is the
>   possibility of retrieving only those keys within a given geographic
>   area - all in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Using Query api , you could do like that , but consider that firebase gives you error on multiple where clauses , here is example of query api call , for you json :

```
Query query = database.child("hotelList").child("hid").orderByChild("latitude").startAt(somevalue).endAt(somevalue);
```

than

`query.addValueEventListener()`.... retrieving data as usual , so it will store filtered data only , as well you need a multiple where clause you can do like that , inside `onDataChange()` , so after data is filtered  :

```
HotelModel room = dataSnapshot.getValue(HotelModel.class);
if(room.getLongtitude() > 123 && room.getLongtitude() < 41321)
{
    //add data to listview or whatever 
}
```